# Military personnel normally put their badges on their shoulders - what is that area called?

Tags: word-choice

I want a word that can sum up one's experiences in a battlefield but I am unable to find the proper terminology for this purpose.

Military badges are normally placed on the left shoulder as well as the upper left chest of military personnels. What is the proper name for these areas which badges would be placed on?

Comment: Also note that the stripes are generally chevrons and in dress uniforms MAY be found on the shoulderboards. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevron_(insignia)

Comment: Why is the answer not shoulder and/or chest?  I'm not sure why you are looking for a different proper name for these parts of the uniform.

Comment: This is unclear. Do you want the area on the uniform or as you state "a word that can sum up one's experiences in a battlefield"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well for the US military that have this practice (many do, I know):

[Shoulder sleeve insignia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoulder_sleeve_insignia) or SSI as an abbreviation.

[image: Shoulder Sleeve Insignia]

Interesting to note that when it is on the right shoulder, it indicates *former* service, not current.

The article linked to above notes that they are not continuing with this custom on newer uniforms, opting for a [Combat Service Identification Badge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combat_Service_Identification_Badge) (CSIB) instead. :-/

Comment: Thanks. Insignia is the precise definition. However, I don't think it's really user friendly (naming a product after this).

Comment: _Insignia_ is the word for the badge, not for the area where the badges are placed, which is what the question asks for.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: True, but other than "top of left shoulder", it seemed most accurate.  "SSI location" perhaps?

Comment: @disappearedng: Do you wish to name a product after this?  You did not say so in your question.  Or do you mean the army should not have named it such?  Military names for items relating to kit tend to be fairly matter of fact.

Comment: Sleeve, upper, insignia for the wearing of. ;-)

Comment: See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epaulette

Comment: @Steve Melnikoff: Epaulettes = curtains for the shoulder.

Comment: @Orbling Actually, the SSI will still be worn on the combat uniform. The new CSIB is just for the new blues.

Comment: Will purists say "insignia" is plural, with singular "insigne"?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the word for shoulders is "epaulettes." Military officers (as opposed to enlisted men) are sometimes referred to as "epaulette boys," because of their shoulder badges.

Comment: You are right that the shoulder strips (on top of the shoulder) are called epaulettes.  @Orbling's picture shows that the badges are not actually on the epaulettes, but the upper sleeve instead.

Comment: @Kit: Military practices have varied over the years. The (modern) picture does show the badge just below the shoulder. And in fact, the caption says "SHOULDER sleeve insignia."But the concept of "epaulettes" goes back some time, at least to the "Three Musketeers."

Comment: @Tom Absolutely and well observed.

Comment: @kit:Is that worth an upvote? Valued more from you, than from most.

Comment: @Tom Gosh, yes. I thought I had, but must have lost track while I was writing the comment.

Comment: @Kit: I've done the same myself from time to time.

Comment: (Former military color guard member here). Epaulettes are specifically limited to referring to the strip on top of the shoulder.

Comment: (Continued...) Epaulettes often do carry insignia. They've existed in some form since Roman times; the name's from the French for "shoulder". In the US military, epaulettes are known as "shoulder straps" or "boards".

"Shoulder marks" are insignia worn on the shoulder straps. They indicate rank, officer status, or military branch. [Wikipedia has a couple decent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoulder_board) but [cursory articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epaulette)on the subject.

I think the OP was referring to the top of the arm, though?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that among service members, the phrase *salad bar* is used informally to refer to the collection of insignia and decorations worn on a uniform.