# Officer's shoulder bars - what are they?

Tags: slang, history

I have read one historical joke, that during the Civil War *Officer's shoulder bars were called "pumpkin rinds"*. Where are these mysterious shoulder bars from? I can find only shoulder *boards* or *straps* on the net. Is it some military slang? Obsolete form? Local variant? Or simply an error of the joke writer?

Comment: http://freepages.genealogy.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~poindexterfamily/CivilWar.html says "pumpkin rinds" are specifically gold lieutenant's bars.

Comment: An image of the gold bars can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Army_officer_rank_insignia

Comment: Related question about [insignia on shoulders](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12666/military-personnel-normally-put-their-badges-on-their-shoulders-what-is-that-a)

Comment: @MetaEd But that page says that 2nd lieutenant bars were not introduced until 1917, which is well after the American Civil War.

Comment: [This link](http://howardlanham.tripod.com/link70.htm) shows some Civil War era epaulettes, and they were yellow and had crescents on them. Second lieutenant was the lowest rank, so "pumpkin rind" as a derisive term probably came from the epaulette's resemblance to a pumpkin rind plus the lowliness of the rank.

Comment: At the time of the Civil War, gold bars were used for first lieutenants. This is according to the same page. What may be creating the confusion is the illustration, which shows how bars are used today, not how they were used in 1851.

Comment: @MetaEd Your comment was the first real answer. Put here an answer, please, so, that I could mark it so.

Comment: Not a language point, but ... I was under the impression that the lowest commissioned officer rank during the Civil War as not 2nd lukey but "ensign", sometimes called "third lieutenant". I just did some Yahooing and I find several references to the rank of ensign being abolished in 1865, which rather implies that it was indeed used before that, but I also find several lists of Civil War ranks, none of which includes ensign. Ah well, not going to pursue it further here. If I cared I'd post something on civilwar.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Also related: [scrambled eggs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrambled_egg_(uniform)).

Comment: @Jay Yes, ensign was traditionaly the lowest possible rank for a gentleman. And later it changed to the lowest rank for a person with education.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shoulder bars are symbols of rank worn, as the name implies, on the shoulder.

Here's a page on ebay where someone is selling a WW2 variety: http://www.ebay.com/itm/WWII-US-NAVY-OFFICER-SHOULDER-BARS-/110564952372

Comment: +1. Thank you, you and MetaEd thus have shown, that it is a normal word. Of military termiology, of course. (Only MetaEd was the first, no offence meant)

Answer (score 6):

They are called [*epaulettes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epaulets).

Comment: According to Wikipedia, [epaulettes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epaulette) are not the same as [shoulder straps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoulder_strap). In fact it appears that you would commonly attach your epaulettes to the shoulder straps of the shirt or jacket. Shoulder bars would be military insignia (bars) which are attached to the shoulder straps.

Comment: @MetaEd: From the same article: "Colloquially, any shoulder straps with marks are also called **epaulettes**."

Comment: Conceded. However I still do not agree that epaulettes would be a word for pumpkin rinds. It appears from the source I cited in my comment on the question that pumpkin rinds are specifically the gold bars, not the straps having the marks on them.

Comment: @MetaEd: It could refer to the fringes on the epaulettes. Who knows? The point is, the OP asked a clear question in his title and the rest of the question is not a marvel of clarity.

Comment: +1 Thank you, my maternal language (Russian) uses this word, too. I only wanted to understand, if the word "bars" could be normally used now, or it is obsolete or slang.

Comment: @Gangrus: Epaulettes (or epaulets) is a catch-all term referring to  the platform for displaying decorations and rank insignia on the shoulder. In American English they are also called "shoulder boards" and if you Google that term the first entry is the Wikipedia link to Epaulettes that I gave in my answer.